# Get options select name from other options select name without form tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have this short code which works with form tags.

```
<select id="district" name="lan" class="country_search"
        onchange="showSubcomune(this.value,this.form.undercomune)">
    <option value="0" selected>choose country </option>
    <option value="10">some comue</option>
</select>

<select name="undercomune" id="undercomune" class="country_search">
    <option value="0" selected >chhose comune</option>
</select>
```

this `showSubcomune` works fine with form tags when i use `this.form.undercomune` so it collecte comunes to selected country and show them in the undercomune select option.

the  problem is i want use same function in other place BUT without html form tag. How can this be `this.form.undercomune` ?? in the function ?

have tried those :

```
this.form.undercomune
this.undercomune
$('#undercomune').val()
```

But no one works .

any help would be much apreciated thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
    function showSubKommun(subCat,selectObj) {
            selectObj.length = 0;


            var j = 0,
            elm;
            for (var k = 0; (elm = kommun[k]); ++k)
            if (elm.lankod == subCat)
                selectObj[j++] = new Option(elm.namn, elm.kommunkod);
        var x = document.getElementById("undercomune");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = " \xAB choose comune \u00bb ";
        option.value = 0;
        x.add(option,x[0]); 
        x[0].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it either by `document.getElementById`

```
var elem = document.getElementById('undercomune');
```

or if you're using jQuery

```
elem = $('#undercomune')[0]; // the indexer returns native html element
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer. i tried yours but i got `selectObj is undefined` in my function . so i added my function in the edit for the sake if you need some more info.

Comment: I used it like that `onchange="showSubKommun(this.value,elem)"` , i defined elem of course  as you said.

Comment: @KarimDaraf why are setting `.length` to 0? It's not an array but you're using it as if it were.

Comment: But it works good with form tags as i said. Just i want use it without form tags.

Comment: ah ok sorry it works now. Sorry i putted now the javascript code after html and it works now :) . before it was javascript before html.

Comment: But i really dont understand why it didnt work js before the html ?

Comment: @KarimDaraf ah! Because the elements are not yet created. You can only access them after they're created :)